# Upper bound $a^k + (1-a)^k$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, real-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

For integer $k \geq 2$ and real $a \in [0, 1]$, I am looking for a function $f(k, a)$ such that

$$
a^k + (1-a)^k \leq f(k, a)
$$

An easy one would be $f(k, a) = 2 \cdot (\max\{a, 1-a\})^k$. However, this bound is not good when $a$ is close to $1$ (or $0$).

Any thought would be helpful.

Side note: This problem came across while I was reading a [paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/tss/files/papers/Ageev-Sviridenko2004_Article_PipageRoundingANewMethodOfCons.pdf).

Comment: Why not study the maximum of the differentiable map $f_k : x\mapsto x^k + (1-x)^k$ by looking at its derivative?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, the maximum for variable $x$ is clearly $1$.  I think the OP is asking about a bound for fixed $a$.

Comment: Can the OP update the question with this precision? The sentence *...given integer $k \ge 2$ and a real $a \in [0,1]$...* is confusing as it seems that all the variables are fixed, hence the upper bound of what?

Comment: $a^2 + (1-a)^2$ as it is decreasing in $k$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is still confusing.

Comment: @BridgelessZen: Are you treating $k$ as a fixed constant and $a$ as a variable?  Or vice-versa?

Comment: Still confusing for me. An upper bound is for a set. I suggest that you explicitly write the set $S$ of which you're looking for the upper bound. It is $S=\{a^k + (1-a)^k \mid k \ge 2\}$ where $a$ is fixed? Or something else?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net He wants a simpler function $f(a,k)$ such that $f(a,k) > a^k + (1-a)^k$ while not being too far off from the correct value.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have edited the question. Hope it is clear this time.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @eyeballfrog Understand now. However, $a^k + (1-a)^k$ is already very simple! What would mean simpler?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The function doesn't have to be "simpler".

Comment: @BridgelessZen Why do you want to do that? What are you looking for? Understanding that would help to answer...

Comment: @BridgelessZen "*An easy one would be $f(k, a) = 2 \cdot (\max\{a, 1-a\})^k$*" $\,$ Or $\,\min(f(k,a), 1)\,$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I see. I will try to elaborate.

Comment: Does anyone mind explaining why this question is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integer $k \ge 2$, you can get a quadratic bound just by forcing the parabola to match at 0, 1/2, and 1:
$$
f(k,a) = 1-4(1-2^{1-k})a(1-a)\ge a^k +(1-a)^k
$$
This is exact for $k = 2,3$ and an upper bound for $k > 3$ because a quadratic doesn't "bow out" as much as higher-order powers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I will play with this bound and see what approximation ratio I can get.

Answer (score 1):

From Taylor around 0 and 1,
$$
a^k + (1-a)^k \leq \min\{ 1-ka+k(k-1)a^2, 1-k(1-a)+k(k-1)(1-a)^2\}
$$
but I don't know if this counts as 'simpler' for you

Comment: Thank you! I will try to understand this bound

Answer (score 1):

For $k\ge 2$, let $g_k$ be defined on $I=[0,1]$ by

$$
g_k(t)=t^k+(1-t)^k.
$$

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
0=g_k'(t)=k[t^{k-1}-(1-t)${k-1}]
&\iff & t^{k-1}=(1-t)^{k-1}\cr
& \iff& t=1-t \cr 
&\iff& t=0.5.
\end{eqnarray}

Since $g''_k(0.5)=2^{1-k}>0$, $g_k$ has a minimum at $t=0.5$

It follows that the maximum of $g_k$ is achieved on the boundary of $[0,1]$. The maximum is then
$$
g_k(0)=g_k(1)=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Erm... sorry, but for $a\in[0,1]$, the expression $a^k + (1-a)^k$ is decreasing as a function of $k$, so $a^2 + (1-a)^2$ would be the most obvious upper bound, since you want $k\ge2$.